# Declaration or statement expected. ts(1128) (11, 1)

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

Im quite new to coding and ive come across an issue which I'm not really sure what the issue is.
Ive been making my discord bot kick/ban command and its giving me the error "Declaration or statement expected. ts(1128) (11, 1)"

Here is my code helps appreciated.

CODE:

```
member.kick().then((member) => {
    message.channel.send(`:wave: ${member.displayName} has been kicked`);
}).catch(() => {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) {
        message.reply("You cannot kick members");
    } else if (member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) {
        message.reply("You cannont kick this member");
    }
})
}
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}ban`)) {

let member = message.mentions.members.first();
member.ban().then((member) => {
    message.channel.send(`:wave: ${member.displayName} has been kicked`);
}).catch(() => {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission(['BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) {
        message.reply("You cannot ban members");
    } else if (member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) {
        message.reply("You cannont ban this member");
    }
})
}
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: What line is the error referencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the code is throwing an error is because you can't check for permissions in a `.catch` block because catch blocks handle errors thrown by code. Instead, you should check for permissions *before* the command is executed. Additionally, you are checking that the user has all three permissions. You can use the JavaScript OR (||) to check that they have any of the permissions and the Administrator permission has ALL PERMISSIONS, eliminating the need to add it to the list. I've rewritten the code below

```js
// You never need to check for ADMINISTRATOR, because it has all permissions
if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
  message.reply("you cannot kick members");
} else if (member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS' || 'BAN_MEMBERS')) {
  message.reply("you cannot kick this member");
}

member.kick()
    .then(member => message.channel.send(`:wave: ${member.displayName} has been kicked`))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}

if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}ban`)) {

let member = message.mentions.members.first();
if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
  message.reply("You cannot ban members")
} else if (member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS' || 'BAN_MEMBERS')) {
  message.reply("You cannont ban this member")
}

member.ban()
  .then(member => message.channel.send(`:wave: ${member.displayName} has been banned`)
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```